Base ABP.io .NET Core docker app will not start on AWS ECS
Using a standard generated Docker file, my ECS tasks will fail to start with this error:

exec /usr/bin/dotnet: exec format error

Abp project creation:
abp new Acme.BookStore -u angular -m none --theme leptonx-lite -csf

Runs fine locally on Windows machine as a Linux container. A base Microsoft Web API template with same configuration will run fine locally and deploy to ECS, so something is different with ABP. Aws logs will only show me the aforementioned log message and the tasks stops.
Docker:
# This stage is used when running from VS in fast mode (Default for Debug configuration)
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081


# This stage is used to build the service project
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
...

Project file:
<TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
...
<DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
<DockerfileContext>..\..</DockerfileContext>

Notes: I get the same results if I publish to ECR with Visual Studio Publish to AWS, docker build, tag, push from the command line, and docker build, tag, push from CodeDeploy. Task setting Operating system/Architecture : Linux/X86_64 both projects.
How do I get ECS or local Docker to tell why it's failing?

exec format error usually means you are building the image for ARM processors, but deploying to an x86 environment, or building for x86 but deploying to an ARM environment. Are you deploying to EC2 or Fargate?

ECS Fargate, aforementioned same system can build a diff solution with docker with no issues no errors.  I am not building it for an ARM.  It's a windows laptop.

Windows is available on both x86 and ARM, so saying it's a Windows laptop doesn't prove anything. Regardless, when you deploy to Fargate are you selecting AWS Graviton (ARM64) or X86_64?

X86_64 both app use exact same config, only difference is the actually projects.

Deleting this question when the bounty expires.  This issue is related to ABP framework crashing the container.   I was able to use Docker Dubug to get inside the container to figure things out.  I don't know why the platform flag can make it bypass the startup issue but it's not a CodeDeploy issue at all.
